# Debug native Android code

Tags: android, gdb, native-code

I'm using Sequoyah to debug native code on Android under eclipse. It works fine if libraries were built with NDK and were located in the project's folder. But there are some libs which were built on another machine. I have its sources, object files and libs are debuggable, but gdb couldn't find sources paths. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it! In eclipse go to Debug Configurations, Source tab and add Path Mapping. In this table you could map compile paths to current paths.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up [path substitution](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#Source-Path) in gdb.

> set substitute-path from to

Comment: thanks for help, seems it's right way, but how to execute this from eclipse. or should i run separately GDB, configure it and somehow save the settings? As i understand, sequoyah-plugin runs and configure gdb, and is it possible to interfere with this process?